# Multiple Data Ranges in a Single Query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a student table now I want to write a query that return a single student in a specified ranges. For example if I provide two ranges (30 to 40) and (40 to 60), query should return me 2 students one which is in the range 30 to 40 and one in the range 40 to 60.
How can I write a single query?

Comment: use `union` for this

Comment: Please provide a sample data from student table. It is not clear if you have range in table and want just one record for each range or  you have exact age or whatever value is in table

Comment: Lets say we have student id and percentage marks and I want to select a single student from each range, note that number of ranges may change they can be a parameter to the query.

Comment: Please dit your question and add some sample data and desired results for that data

Answer (score 2):

Use two selects with different ranges in where statement combined by [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Example:

```
(SELECT * FROM students WHERE ranges BETWEEN 30 AND 40 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM students WHERE ranges BETWEEN 40 AND 60 LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: What if we want to make the number of ranges configurable because in this solution we will have to write another select for every range.

Comment: Yes, you have to build select for each range. There is no other way, afaik. But you can build dynamic sql, don't you ?

Comment: So we can take it as a sql query restriction.

Comment: Yes we can build on that thanks for pointing in the right direction it was really help full.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` condition:

`(range between 30 and 40) OR (range between 40 and 60)`.

and `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN range between 30 and 40 then 'X' else 'Y' as CLASS
```

and then you can use `GROUP BY` to select 1 record for class so:

```
SELECT MAX(STUDENT_ID), CASE WHEN range between 30 and 40 then 'X' else 'Y' as CLASS
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CLASS
```

Comment: but how to make sure we have single entry in the result for each Range

Comment: So if there are 2  records in range 30-40 ? :)

Comment: I was missing: "one which is in the range 30 to 40 and one in the range 40 to 60." I edited my question. @AlexKapustin

Comment: Quite tricky solution :) and if there are no requirements to show more than 1 record from range could be solution. Well done @niknik

Comment: The solution with UNION is more better and optimal, especially if you have a big amount of entries (-;